# Found non-literal argument to RegExp Constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint

I have a function where I am using the regex like below, but ESLINT is throwing warning for me.

`Warning: Found non-literal argument to RegExp Constructor  security/detect-non-literal-regexp`

```
const getHighlightedText = useCallback((text, highlight) => {
    const parts = text.split(new RegExp(`(${highlight})`, 'gi'))
    return (
      <span>
        {parts.map((part) => (
          <span
            key={Math.random()}
            className={
              part.toLowerCase() === highlight.toLowerCase() ? 'text-black' : ''
            }
          >
            {part}
          </span>
        ))}
      </span>
    )
  }, [])
```

Any suggestions on how to write the below regex

`const parts = text.split(new RegExp(`(${highlight})`, 'gi'))`

Comment: In your case, that's a false positive so you should disable that check for this line.